# Is there a connection between the $g$-factor of $2$ and the value $1/2$ of electron spin?

Tags: quantum-spin, dipole-moment

When the $g$-factor of an electron ($g_e$) is approx. $2.00$, this suggests that there is a relationship with the electron being a spin $1/2$ particle.

I write electron spin magnetic dipole moment as $\mu_s = g_e \,\mu_{\text{Bohr}} \, (S /\hbar)$
and electron angular magnetic dipole moment as $\mu_l = g_l \,\mu_{\text{Bohr}} \, (L /\hbar)$.

The electron in hydrogen ground state has $L=\hbar$ and $g_l=1$
and the electron spin has $S=0.5 \hbar$ and $g_S=2$.

So $\mu_s = \mu_l = \mu_{\text{Bohr}}$.
Is there any idea why it is natural or to be expected that an electron in the hydrogen ground state has $\mu_s = \mu_l$ because
surely there is no such thing as coincidence.
I know the Dirac equation calculates this, but it doesn't explain why this is natural or to be expected. There must also be a hidden reason, any ideas?

Let's exclude the strong interaction.

Comment: It's a rather moot point because there are no $1/4$ spin particles.

Comment: There is a connection between $g = 2$ and spin $= 1/2$. There is a great deal of interest in the relationship at the moment. See [What does the Muon g-2 experiment tell us?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCCGr4BqElE&list=PLCfRa7MXBEsoJuAM8s6D8oKDPyBepBosS&index=4) for more.

Comment: In the video I don't find any hints about the connection, it's about the fact that g-factor of electron and muon is a little bit higher than 2.

Comment: The connection comes from the Dirac equatin.

Comment: Yes I still want to try and study that equation! Still this is so remarkable that surely there must be some speculation about it's deeper meaning this cannot be a coincidence?

Comment: I don't get all the downvotes here. It's a perfectly good question even if the answer is "probably not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation. For example, the proton and neutron also have spin $1/2$, yet their g-factor is $5.6$ and $-3.8$, respectively (cf. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-factor_(physics)#Measured_g-factor_values)). On the other hand, the W-boson has spin $1$ yet its g-factor is also $2$, as the electron's.

See also [arXiv:hep-ph/0607187](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0607187).

Comment: Better not to use protons and neutrons in the explanation since these are not elementary particles.

Comment: And for muon (which _is_ elementary) the g-factor is very close to that of electron.

Answer (score -1):

I would more say, that g-factor is related with the intrinsic magnetic moment of **elementary particles** $μ$ and not with their spin $S$.

The g-factor=**2** *denotes* that an **elementary particle** (i.e. not combinatoric) has an intrinsic generated magnetic field in the form of magnetic **dipole** charge creating a magnetic moment in space. The value of 2 indicates the number of magnetic poles in the field (i.e. magnetic dipole).

Therefore all elementary particles which posses an *intrinsic* magnetic moment (i.e. magnetic dipole, N-S) are having a natural g-factor=2 value *independent* their spin S value as very nicely reported by AccidentalFourierTransform.

Comment: Are you saying the $g$-factor must be $2$ because a $2$-pole (dipole) has $2$ poles? Angular momentum dipole has $g$-factor $1$.

Comment: @Gerard Exactly. Yes the classical angular momentum dipole has gyromagnetic ratio equal 1 but Dirac showed that the quantum value is g-factor=2 . This  also proofs that  the nature of the intrinsic magnetic moment of the electron is not actually due a closed loop circulation of electron charges, current,  (which is a contradiction, a circulation of electrons inside an electron?...) thus Amperian but instead Gilbertian in nature thus consists of two opposite magnetic charges (poles) joint in a dipole formation. Therefore magnetic monopoles can exist in nature only in a dipole formation.

Comment: So does the electron's magnetic field have 2.0023 poles?..

Comment: @Ruslan "So does the electron's magnetic field have 2.0023 poles?.." Good question. The anomalous magnetic dipole moment of the electron $α=(g-2)/2$ is thought today to be not intrinsic to the electron but due to its interaction with its environment and is an effective value added to the Dirac intrinsic value of 2. The electron interacts with its immediate environment like virtual particles and even it is assumed possible new undiscovered particles (e.g. dark matter candidates). For more details see g-2 muon experiment in Fermilab. So, no. The electron has intrinsically 2 poles.